# Airflow CrossSuper DAG Dependency Check

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I had a scenario where there are two DAG's one is Super DAG which had to trigger 10 jobs. If all the 10 Jobs are successful then only trigger the second DAG. At this point we had an external sensor placed in 2nd DAG where it checks only the success status of 10th Job in first DAG and triggers the second DAG.

Also we had dependencies set up for each successor job in first Super DAG(if the 1st job is success then only trigger 2nd job so on until 10th -- But this is not working for out for our scenario due to task skip some times).

Need to check only if all the 10 jobs in first DAG are successful triggerred then only trigger the second DAG. Can any one please suggest how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

With questions like these, it helps to see code of what you already tried and what didn't work. It sounds like a `TriggerDagRunOperator` is an easier solution in your situation because that requires only a single operator in the first DAG. For example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

with DAG(dag_id="super_dag", schedule=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)):
    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")
    trigger_jobs = [BashOperator(task_id=f"job_{i}", bash_command="echo 'run job {i}'") for i in range(10)]
    trigger_second_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id="trigger_second_dag", trigger_dag_id="second_dag")
    start >> trigger_jobs >> trigger_second_dag

with DAG(dag_id="second_dag", schedule=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)):
    EmptyOperator(task_id="demo")
```

With this code, you have "super_dag":

[image]

With default settings, the `trigger_second_dag` task only starts if all 10 jobs succeed, and it then triggers the second DAG:

[image]

The play icon indicates it was triggered externally.